# monitoring directory on another pc

Tags: java, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

I want to monitor a folder located on another computer using the `FileSystemWatcher`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, your computer A wants to observe a directory on the hard drive of computer B.  Here are some ways to achieve this:

- Have computer A mount the remote file system on B using SMB, NFS or some other network file system protocol.  Then your application running on A should be able to:

  - use a Java 7 WatchService to get file system events on the directory,
  - in Java 6 and earlier, poll the directory's modification date etc to see when it changes, or
  - use a native program or library to read Linux `inotify(7)` events or the Windows equivalent.
- If you can't mount B's file system on A, you need to implement and run some kind of remote service on B that can be queried by a client application running on A.  There are many possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which platform you are running, or on which filesystem are remote directory available.If you are on windows, just map remote directory using command NET USE, on linux, you can mount by NFS, SSHFS,FTPFS (fuse) or anything else.Java just needs to be folder mounted in filesystem hierarchy.